# Remove black bar from UIPagingViewController dot indicators

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I have a `UIPageViewController` set up. There's a black bar that appears under the dot indicators. Is there anyway to remove the black bar? Thanks. [image]

**UPDATE:**
I have learned that the bar you see by the page indicators is part of the `UIPageViewController`. Therefore making it clear, or any color is just changing the color of the page view controller which lays behind whatever view your on now. So if you have an image as a background and you don't want the bar don't use UIPageViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[UIAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)** to change the color of `UIPageControl`. Otherwise it is not accessible.

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

You can add this code for example in the app's delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Please have a look. You can add this code for example in app's delegate.